# Upgrade CakePHP 2.X to 4.X

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to upgrade CakePHP2.x TO CakePHP4.x, I have WAMP 3.2.3 and Php 7.4. Downloaded CakePHP4.X but the entire directory structure is different between CakePHP2 and 4, if anyone share some idea how I can upgrade, that would be very helpful, share me the best way to achieve it.
Thank You!!

Comment: There is loads of documentation out there about upgrading from 2.x to 3.x and then from 3.x to 4.x, and tools to help. You wouldn't complete one upgrade before starting the next, but rather reference both sets of documentation in doing you one upgrade. Though, the way a lot of people have found best is just to have Cake "bake" the entire skeleton of the new app for you (it should do fairly well, if you've followed database naming standards), and then move their old business logic into the new structure.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, Thanks for your response, we moved entire portal to django, since the deployment is easy  and I'm not familiar with PHP so, jumping two version is difficult so we picked up python django

Comment: @GregSchmidt that sounds like a great idea, at least so far as Business Logic goes. How well does that strategy work for View logic?

Comment: I'd say that views are easier to migrate than business logic. The relations between data are a little different, and the conversion from arrays to entity objects needs addressing, but I did most of both of those with regex search-and-replace. (Don't ask for examples, it was years ago!)